# Laravel Forge Quick Deploy throwing 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, forge, laravel-forge

I've set up all configurations at Laravel Forge, and created new site connected to Bitbucket Git repository.

When I click "Enable Quick Deploy" the button an error is thrown, whereas "Deploy Now" works well.

`https://forge.laravel.com/servers/{myserver}/sites/{mysite}/deploy 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I found out this link which has similar issue to me : https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1676-laravel-forge-deploy-and-quick-deploy-not-working/0

Only one different thing is that mine happens to the 'Quick Deploy'.

Do you know any reason why it happens?

Comment: Did you change your repository origin? It happens to me just a couple of days ago (switching from bitbucket to github). You can also try to connect ssh on your server, run `git pull origin master` then retry quick deploy (maybe there is a certificate you need to approvate manually)

Comment: @rap-2-h I tried to connect ssh on my server and then run `git pull origin stage`, but still same error happens when I click the quick deploy button. Is is because of repository? Yes, I've changed my repository origin. I'm wondering the quick deployment is only working for a master branch?

Comment: Ok, if you changed your repository origin, it can be the same problem. There is something to do in forge back-office (so today, only the administrator of Forge can do something for you, there is nothing in interface to do such a thing). So you have to contact Forge support (that's what I done, and they changed something in their database). One last question: does it work if you click on `deploy now` ? (it should not work either, if it's what I think).

Comment: @rap-2-h Thanks, I've asked Forge support and then got a response. It's a permission problem.  I posted the answer as well. FYI, the `deploy now` works. Only the `quick deploy` didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this response about it from Taylor(Laravel Forge) directly.

> ### Taylor said:
>
> This means there is a permission error on your source control provider such as GitHub and we are unable to add a service hook.
>
> You can try refreshing your access token in your Forge account panel on that “Authentication” tab. Then I would verify on GitHub / Bitbucket that 3rd party integrations are not disabled - this is an unfortunate default on GitHub

I followed his instruction, refreshed the access token in the Forge account panel, and allowed the Forge access on Bitbucket Integrations, then it works! (I'm using Bitbucket.)

It means that the forge didn't have a permission which allows me to extend what Bitbucket does when the repository changes.

Answer (score 0):

Forge -> Server -> Site -> Meta -> Copy deploy key -> Paste to Github/organisation/site/settings/deploy keys