# Laravel Forge 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, server, forge, http-status-code-500

I have updated the git repository (`developer` branch - this is the only branch on the repo) and deploy on Forge but I am getting `500 Internal Server Error`

.env configurations are correct (database, username, password and other configs.)

Also, PHP version on the server is 7.2 and this same site has worked before When I made the last push (changes: routes and controller functions) it started showing the error.

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491431/laravel-forge-quick-deploy-throwing-500-error) but even after following these steps the 500 error is showing!

Any suggestion how can I solve this issue!?

PS: I am new to Forge!

Comment: Can you get to the log files? If so, check what the error is exactly.

Comment: No errors on the log file!

Comment: All of the logs? Like the nginx/apache, php and laravel itself?

Comment: I had some errors (laravel.log ) while I was codding but I already fixed them! In Forge I cannot find the error log file (I checked the laravel.log file on repo - but it's missing)

Comment: Add `APP_DEBUG=true` to your `.env`. You will see a more detailed error message.

Comment: @kotapeter thank you! Now I see what the error is! I am using LaravelFCM for Firebase push notifications, and some of the class files are missing. I am, sure that I pushed all the files but I'll check again!

Comment: Your branch is up to date with 'origin/developer'. But the vendor folder is missing from the repository. I think that's the reason why the error 500 is showing. I have composer update and composer install before (push-ing and) deploying to the Forge. Any sugesstions?

Comment: You need to run the composer update and composer install on the Forge.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you very much guys :)

Answer (score 1):

i know this is a very late reply i had the same issue 
check your routes something is conflicting

Comment: More detail on what exactly to check and how would be useful.